# 'AppearanceWhenContainedIn' is deprecated

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I recently installed a new Cocoapod ChameleonFramework, and right off the bat I am getting an error in the framework. It is telling me

> 'appearanceWhenContainedIn:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS
>   9.0 - Use +appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses: instead

I am really not sure what to do, and this code is written in Objective-C and I really don't have much knowledge in Objective-C, I only know Swift. As a result any help would be appreciated. Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
#import "UIAppearance+Swift.h"

@implementation UIView (UIViewAppearance_Swift)

+ (instancetype)appearanceWhenContainedWithin: (NSArray *)containers {

NSUInteger count = containers.count;
NSAssert(count <= 10, @"The count of containers greater than 10 is not supported.");

return [self appearanceWhenContainedIn:
        count > 0 ? containers[0] : nil,
        count > 1 ? containers[1] : nil,
        count > 2 ? containers[2] : nil,
        count > 3 ? containers[3] : nil,
        count > 4 ? containers[4] : nil,
        count > 5 ? containers[5] : nil,
        count > 6 ? containers[6] : nil,
        count > 7 ? containers[7] : nil,
        count > 8 ? containers[8] : nil,
        count > 9 ? containers[9] : nil,
        nil];
}

@end
```

This may seem like a really simple question, but I really don't know much Objective-C, so any help with resolving this issue would help me out a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up the people who write this CocoaPod to keep it up to date; contact them. Meanwhile, this is not your code, so do nothing. The code will work just fine for now, so no action is called for.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will email them. However, in the mean time is there anyway I could fix this or would I have to wait for them to release a new update to the pod.

Comment: You could fix it, but do you really want to change somebody else's code? If you're going to take ownership, you would want to maintain the code yourself — and you've said you're not prepared to do that.

Comment: True, I will probably wait for a newer release of ChameleonFramework.

Comment: If there is a test for this functionality, go ahead and fix it and submit a pull request. If there isn't a test for this you can write one or ask yourself if you really want to include someone else's untested code in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is not recommended to change someone's code you don't know. But eventually
there is someone facing this warning:

Just replace `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` with `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:` that's all.

E.g.

```
// old code
[[UIScrollView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[self class], nil] 
setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// new code
[[UIScrollView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[self class]]] 
setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: Many thanks for this posting. I clicked on automatically fixing of this warning. But after that the most challenging part for me was @[[self class]]] .